# How long do certain Meteor data sources live for?

Tags: meteor

A MiniMongo Collection usually gets synced to the Mongo Collection so its life is basically forever.

I would like to store a `Shopping Cart` object. When a user is logged in, storing and managing how long that shopping cart data lasts for is easy. But what about when a user is not logged in? You don't want them to navigate to other parts of the website or even refresh the page and completely wipe out their shopping cart. But you also don't want to store the shopping cart for too long. Storing the contents for a day or a few hours should suffice.

How long does a miniMongo Local Collection ( `new Mongo.Collection("null");` ) last? Could I store the shopping cart contents in a Local Colection or does the collection get wiped on page refresh?

Likewise, how long does a Session variable last?

--- Summary of Answers ---

- Session Variable - dies after a page refresh, reactive
- Local Collection - dies after a page refresh, reactive
- LocalStorage API - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage, persists for different periods of time ranging from forever to when a tab is closed, NOT reactive, different browsers have different ways of storing and retrieving from LocalStorage, so complex to code.
- LocalStorage using Amplify - http://amplifyjs.com/ - basically an easier way to use the LocalStorage API.
- Store data into a Mongo Collection with a timestamp. Use that timestamp to run a cronjob that periodically deletes the data after a set amount of time - reactive, persists across all computers and browsers, gives you complete control over how and when the data expires, takes a bit more coding and setup

Comment: Maybe the code should store timestamps and expiration dates on database objects when they are created.  Also, session variables are stored in HTML5 local storage.  As such, they are tied to browsers and thus you can't rely on that for storing information that must be available from some other browser, i.e. mobile vs fixed, home vs office, etc.

Comment: @Paul, HTML5 local storage - interesting. It appears that there are two types: HTML local storage provides two objects for storing data on the client:

window.localStorage - stores data with no expiration date
code.sessionStorage - stores data for one session (data is lost when the tab is closed)
I wonder what type Session uses? What about Local Collections? Are they also in HTML5 Local Storage?

Comment: "The HTML5 sessionStorage object is equal to the localStorage object, except that it stores the data for only one session. The data is deleted when the user closes the browser window."

Based on this, I'm going to guess that a Meteor Session variable is stored as an HTML5 SessionStorage Object and lives for as long as the user has the tab open?

Comment: Now I am not so sure.  I went to meteorpad.com, popped up a chrome debug window and did `Session.set('name','Me')`, which the Meteor app took.  Looking in localStorage and sessionStorage, 'name' is not to be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Session variables and local collections will be erased after a page refresh, so you can eliminate those from your list of possibilities.

An alternative is to store the cart data in [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html). You can do so with direct calls to the localStorage API, or with a polyfill like [amplify.js](http://amplifyjs.com/) ([meteor package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/amplify)) if you need to support older browsers. The only problem with this approach is that it won't work across browsers/computers, and it won't be reactive between tabs.

My recommendation would be to store the cart data in a collection which maintains an `updatedAt` timestamp. Then add a [cron job](https://atmospherejs.com/percolatestudio/synced-cron) which periodically removes all carts where `updatedAt` is older than X hours. This has the advantage of working reactively across tabs/browsers/computers, and you'll have full control over when the carts expire (including adding fancy rules like not expiring the cart if the user happens to be connected).

Comment: I've added a summary of my findings to the OP.

Comment: how would you link a Shopping Cart saved to the database with someone who never logged in? If the user was logged in at the time of creating the shopping cart, everything is easy. But if the user never logs in, how to you connect this temporary shopping cart with a non-logged-in user?

Comment: I'd use local storage. When you detect that the user has logged in, just remove the data from local storage and insert it into the collection. It's not as nice, but in the absence a unique user identifier it's probably the best you can do.

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny You may want to check out how this is done in [natestrauser:cart](https://atmospherejs.com/natestrauser/cart).

Answer (score 1):

GroundDB aims to make a thin wrapper on top of Collections API so you can persist connections locally without much coding overhead, even for offline access. when you reconnect data is refreshed.
https://github.com/GroundMeteor/db